# Java Web application thread getting stuck for DB operation at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, tomcat, connection-pooling

I am facing problem where sometimes web application thread getting stuck at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) for DB operations.My app server and DB server resides in different VMs.
Please find below JStack

```
"http-bio-9904-exec-10" #57 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0     tid=0x00007f1730007000 nid=0xfcd1 runnable [0x00007f171e6ee000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:174)
- locked <0x00000000f6a35bb8> (a com.mysql.cj.core.io.ReadAheadInputStream)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at com.mysql.cj.core.io.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:58)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:60)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:48)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:51)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:521)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.checkErrorPacket(MysqlaProtocol.java:723)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.sendCommand(MysqlaProtocol.java:662)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlaProtocol.java:950)
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlaSession.java:431)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1974)
- locked <0x00000000f6a2ce30> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1936)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:891)
- locked <0x00000000f6a2ce30> (a com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:795)
.
.
.
.
```

I am using tomcat 7.0.57 with tomcat pooling as DB pool
Following is the pooling configuration

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/xyz" auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"     
maxTotal="100" 
maxIdle="30"      
factory= "com.XXX.tomcat.jndi.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"            

maxWaitMillis="10000" 
username="abc" password="abcdef" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"       
url="jdbc:mysql://x.y.z.w:3306/some_db" 
testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1">
</Resource>
```

I checked at the DB server(Mysql 5.6.34) in the general logs and found that query is reaching DB server after some minutes(varies between 5-20 minutes).
Sometimes the query(both insert/select) is executed with in fraction of seconds.

In the TCP dump at app level also shows the same results where there is a delay of 5-20 minutes.

Some of the observations:
There is a slot of time like 5-10 minutes in which if request is fired the response is obtained after 15 minutes and after that 5-10 minutes all the queries will work smoothly for next 30-40 minutes.

Mysql driver used is 5.1.0.

Please help me in identifying what can be the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Atlast I got the problem.People facing the similar issue can give a try for same.
It was actully a result of firewall i have in my network.I resolved it using connection pool setting.
The final pool configuration made it work fr me.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/xxx"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="com.yyy.tomcat.jndi.EncryptedDataSourceFactory"
    username="xyz"
    password="abc"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/abc?enableQueryTimeouts=true&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;autoReconnectForPools=true"
    initialSize="0"
    maxTotal="100"
    maxActive="100"
    minIdle="0"
    maxWait="1000"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    testWhileIdle="true"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
    validationInterval="30000"
    validationQueryTimeout="1"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="10"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    logValidationErrors="true"
    connectionProperties="[enableQueryTimeouts=true]"
    jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;QueryTimeoutInterceptor(queryTimeout=1);SlowQueryReport;ResetAbandonedTimer">
```

Comment: What actual setting was it that fixed the problem?